# Alternative to generate Local Cube for Tabular data model in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, dax, ssas-tabular

Just a quick question, im new to the Sql Server Analysis Service environment and still experimenting with it. As what im aware of, for multidimensional model, we can use MDX Script to generate a local cube for ad hoc data query through excel pivot table. Since MDX is not applicable to tabular data model, may i know if there's an alternative where i can do something like this (generating local cube) but, for tabular data model? perhaps using DAX

Appreciate all the answer and feedback. =)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing like local cubes for SSAS tabular
however you could use PowerBI (or PowerPivot in Excel) to create a Model which can then be easily shared

Comment: i see... Thank you for sharing @GerhardBrueckl